# Iterate and ouput conditional data from a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

I have a json file called steps.json which contains this json array that I'd like to iterate over based on the conditions below.

```
{
"friends": [
    { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "Step": 2 },
    { "firstName" : "Sharon", "lastName" : "Thomas", "Step": 3 },
    { "firstName" : "Thomas", "lastName" : "Harris", "Step": 3 },
    { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Lee", "Step": 4 },
    { "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Young", "Step": 4 },
    { "firstName" : "Shirley", "lastName" : "Perez", "Step": 4 },
    { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Lee", "Step": 5 },
    { "firstName" : "Mary", "lastName" : "White", "Step": 5 },
    { "firstName" : "Matthew", "lastName" : "Garcia", "Step": 5 },
    { "firstName" : "Patricia", "lastName" : "Allen", "Step": 5 },
    { "firstName" : "Larry", "lastName" : "Robinson", "Step": 6 },
    { "firstName" : "Kimberly", "lastName" : "Lopez", "Step": 6 },
    { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Martinez", "Step": 6 },
    { "firstName" : "Deborah", "lastName" : "Walker", "Step": 6 },
    { "firstName" : "Joseph", "lastName" : "Lopez", "Step": 6 },
    { "firstName" : "Dorothy", "lastName" : "Moore", "Step": 7 },
    { "firstName" : "Jose", "lastName" : "Jackson", "Step": 7 },
    { "firstName" : "Karen", "lastName" : "Lee", "Step": 7 },
    { "firstName" : "Paul", "lastName" : "Taylor", "Step": 7 },
    { "firstName" : "Amy", "lastName" : "Gonzalez", "Step": 7 },
    { "firstName" : "Richard", "lastName" : "Martinez", "Step": 7 }
]
}
```

I am trying to output the objects in the array when a user clicks a button that matches the step number. 
Example if the user clicks button 2 I want to show all the friends that are in step 2 and so on and so forth. I am getting the json like so but not sure how to set up the click request.

```
findFriends :function(){
        var urlString = 'assets/javascripts/steps.json';

        $.getJSON(urlString,function(data){
            var friends = data.friends;
            for(var i = 0; i <= friends.length; i++){
                for(friend in friends[i]){

                }
            }


        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code.  Click the button below to run it.

```js
$(function() {
  var friends = [{
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Taylor",
    "Step": 2
  }, {
    "firstName": "Sharon",
    "lastName": "Thomas",
    "Step": 3
  }, {
    "firstName": "Thomas",
    "lastName": "Harris",
    "Step": 3
  }, {
    "firstName": "Deborah",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "Step": 4
  }, {
    "firstName": "Mark",
    "lastName": "Young",
    "Step": 4
  }, {
    "firstName": "Shirley",
    "lastName": "Perez",
    "Step": 4
  }, {
    "firstName": "Joseph",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "Step": 5
  }, {
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "White",
    "Step": 5
  }, {
    "firstName": "Matthew",
    "lastName": "Garcia",
    "Step": 5
  }, {
    "firstName": "Patricia",
    "lastName": "Allen",
    "Step": 5
  }, {
    "firstName": "Larry",
    "lastName": "Robinson",
    "Step": 6
  }, {
    "firstName": "Kimberly",
    "lastName": "Lopez",
    "Step": 6
  }, {
    "firstName": "Jose",
    "lastName": "Martinez",
    "Step": 6
  }, {
    "firstName": "Deborah",
    "lastName": "Walker",
    "Step": 6
  }, {
    "firstName": "Joseph",
    "lastName": "Lopez",
    "Step": 6
  }, {
    "firstName": "Dorothy",
    "lastName": "Moore",
    "Step": 7
  }, {
    "firstName": "Jose",
    "lastName": "Jackson",
    "Step": 7
  }, {
    "firstName": "Karen",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "Step": 7
  }, {
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Taylor",
    "Step": 7
  }, {
    "firstName": "Amy",
    "lastName": "Gonzalez",
    "Step": 7
  }, {
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Martinez",
    "Step": 7
  }];

  function findFriends(step) {
    var urlString = 'assets/javascripts/steps.json';
    // commenting out the ajax lines for the purposes of this demo.  for now we'll use the global friends variable declared above
    // $.getJSON(urlString, function(data) {
    //  var friends = data.friends;

    var results = '';
    var numFound = 0;
    $.each(friends, function(key, value) {
      if (value.Step == step) {
        numFound++;
        console.log (numFound);
        if (numFound <= 2) {
          results += value.firstName + ' ' + value.lastName + '<br>';
        }
      };
    });
    if (numFound > 2) {
      results += 'and ' + (numFound - 2) + 
      ' other friend' + (numFound == 3 ? '' : 's');
    }
    

    $('#results').html(results);


    //});
  }

  $('#find-friends').click(function() {
    // note the plus to convert the string into a number
    findFriends(+$('#step').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter the step you want to test:
<br>
<input type="text" id="step">
<br>
<button id="find-friends">click me!</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: **thank you very much**. I need to change the condition slightly to only show the first two people at any step. so for example if had three friends at step 4 and i click the button to see step 4 i need to out put "Deborah Lee, Shirley Perez, and 1 other friend are also in Baby Step 4"

Answer (score 0):

```
// friend finder function
function findFriends(stepNo) {
  var urlString = 'assets/javascripts/steps.json';

  $.getJSON(urlString, function(data){
    var friends = data.friends.filter(function(friend) {
      return friend.Step === stepNo;        
    });


    // do something with the found friends :) (e.g. fill a list)
  });
}

// click handler
$('.yourButtonSelector').click(function() {
    var stepNo = $(this).attr('data-stepNo'); // not sure how you store the step no. in the buttons

    findFriends(stepNo);
});
```

As a side note: if you have control over the JSON format and use this service mainly for the described format, I'd recommend using the `stepNo` as the key:

```
{
  friends: {
    1: [...],
    2: [...],
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`[].filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this.

```
 friends.filter(function(f){return f.step == 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here num is dynamic value which you can pass and based on each index it will filter

```
var friends = data.friends;    
var num = 6;
var filteredNames = $(friends).filter(function( idx ) {
return friends[idx].Step === num; 
});
```